# How to read file line by line abd write it to file based on condition. in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read file line by line first perform some operation on first value then want to read second value from file again want to perform some operation
Eg.if I have one file which have values
Vik
John
Lisa

I want to read one by one and pass to sql server and write the output(age) based  on gender in file
If name started with Vik is male then write his age in file male.txt else female.txt
Could you please help me on this

**code**:

```
with open('C:\code\out.txt', 'r') as content_file:
  for line in content_file:
    cs=pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',server = '.', database = 'Test')
    tablequery="select Age,Gender from dbo.AuditSource where Name='" + line+"'";
    cursor = cs.cursor()
    cursor.execute(tablequery)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        age=row.Age
        Gen=row.Gender
        print(age)
        if Gen=='M':
            with open('C:\code\male.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(age) #here getting error not able toe write var value

        else:
            with open('C:\code\female.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(age) #here getting error not able toe write var value
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to read value one by one from file pass that value to sql server and want to write sql server output to another file based on condition

Answer (score 0):

This is the code what you are asking.

```
search = open("some.txt","r") #opens and read file        
for line in search:
   new  = line[0]
   if new == "V":
      file = open("edit.txt","w")
      file.write(line)
```